# How to keep let when litner wants to change it to const

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to output my isChecked value to the parent component. This vaulue keeps information if the checkbox is clicked or not. I cannot change it to const because I have an assignement below. My linter says to fix it by changing to const. Can anyone help me with that? I want it to be mutable

```
export class CheckboxConfigureComponent {

@Input() selectedProperty: DateRowConfigDto | LabelRowConfigDto | EnumRowConfigDto
@Output() filterEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>()

constructor() {
}

updateFilter(): void {
    let isChecked: boolean;
    isChecked = this.selectedProperty.visible ?  true : false
    this.filterEvent.emit(isChecked)
}
}
```

> 'isChecked' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead prefer-const ✖ 3 problems (3 errors, 0 warnings) 1 error and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option. husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)

Comment: Why do you separate the definition and assignment? If you didn't do that, it _could_ be const.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a const, because the value is only changed in one place:

```
updateFilter(): void {
    const isChecked = this.selectedProperty.visible ? true : false;
    this.filterEvent.emit(isChecked);
}
```

And you can even simplify the assignment:

```
updateFilter(): void {
    const isChecked = this.selectedProperty.visible;
    this.filterEvent.emit(isChecked);
}
```

Or don't use `isChecked at all`:

```
updateFilter(): void {
    this.filterEvent.emit(this.selectedProperty.visible);
}
```